# php for loop of an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop

I have an html form that passes an array into php and then does a for loop to print out values. This is the code that I have

```
$payloads = $_POST['topay'];
$loadNum = $_POST['loadnum'];
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$driver = $_POST['driver'];

for($i=0;$i<count($payloads);$i++)
    {
        echo $payloads[$i];
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<td width="50" valign="top">'.$loadNum[$i].'</td>';
        echo '<td width="50" valign="top">'.$unit[$i].'</td>';
        echo '<td width="150" valign="top">'.$driver[$i].'</td>';
    }
```

the $_POST['topay'] is a checkbox array that I pass in where only the items that are checked will come through. For example in the form that I pass to php there are multiple check boxes, and it should only pass the ones that are checked. When I do the first echo in the for loop it correctly prints out the values, but the echos within the  do not.

Values:

```
$loadNum = [5,6]
$unit = [101,103]
driver = ["joe", "mike"]
```

When both of these checkboxes are checked, the output works correctly. When the first checkbox is checked, the output works correctly. However, if I only check the second one (6, 103, "mike"), the output still comes out for (5,101,"joe")

**EDIT:**
here is the HTML code that i send to this php page:

```
echo '<form action="statement.php" target="_blank" METHOD="post">';
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="topay[]" value="'.$loadNumber.'" checked></td>';
echo '<td width="70"><input type="hidden" name="loadnum[]" value="'.$loadNumber.'" />'. $loadNumber.'</td>';
echo '<td width="70"><input type="hidden" name="unit[]" value="'.$unit.'" />' .$unit.'</td>';
echo '<td width="150"><input type="hidden" name="driver[]" value="'.$driver.'" />' .$driver.'</td>';
?>
<p><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Create Statement" /></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but the echos within the do not."? also, can you post the html form also, thanks.

Comment: please post your html code....

Comment: You need to set your form input keys to be the same, and then echo only the checked key.

Comment: Agreed, please post your form code. I need to know what exactly is `$payloads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have properly named the input values, e.g.:

```
<input name="topay[0]" type="checkbox">
<input name="loadnum[0]" value="5">
<input name="unit[0]" value="101">
<input name="driver[0]" value="joe">

<input name="topay[1]" type="checkbox">
<input name="loadnum[1]" value="6">
<input name="unit[1]" value="103">
<input name="driver[1]" value="mike">
```

Take note of the `topay[0]` and `topay[1]` notation that I'm using, as opposed to your form input values that use `topay[]`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="topay[]" value=" ...
<input type="hidden" name="loadnum[]" ...
<input type="hidden" name="unit[]" ...
```

Checkbox field values are only sent at form submission if they're checked, so this will be sent:

- If only the first checkbox is checked -> `[5]`
- If both checkboxes are checked -> `[5, 6]`
- If only the second checkbox is checked -> `[6]`

Using the naming scheme I've suggested earlier, this would be sent:

- If only the first checkbox is checked -> `[5]`
- If both checkboxes are checked -> `[5, 6]`
- If only the second checkbox is checked -> `[1 => 6]`

With those field names corrected, you should iterate the `$payloads` array using `foreach` so that you can get the *associative key* out as well; this is important, because only checked values are sent with the form.

```
foreach ($payloads as $key => $payload) {
    echo $payload, '<br>';
    printf('<td width="50" valign="top">%s</td>', $loadNum[$key]);
    printf('<td width="50" valign="top">%s</td>', $unit[$key]);
    printf('<td width="50" valign="top">%s</td>', $driver[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same result. If both of the checkboxes are checked, I will get both of the outputs. If the first checkbox is checked, i'll also get the correct output. But if ony the 2nd checkbox is checked, it outputs the first values (5,101,"joe")

Comment: @HarisP That shouldn't happen with the code and HTML I've put in my answer; it would help if you added into your question the output of `var_dump($_POST);` when you've only checked the second checkbox.

Comment: @HarisP The problem is that you're using `topay[]` and not `topay[0]` and `topay[1]`, like in my answer.